# Fb.login: need to press login button twice for console.log to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, console.log, fbconnect

Please note: This is not a duplicate, since the other thread gives a solution that already implemented in my code, yet the problem still persist.

I am using Facebook Javascript SDK with a custom login button:

```
<button id="login" onclick="javascript:login();">Login Facebook</button>
```

and javascript:

```
function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {

                FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name, email' },
                    function(response) {
                        email = response.email;
                        name = response.name;
                    }
                );

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                   // alert(user_id);
                });

                console.log('Response goes here! ' + email + ' of ' + name + ' of ' + user_id);

            }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
        }
```

For some reason, I observe this behavior:

When I press login button once I am connected but no `console.log` is shown.

When I press login button for second time, `console.log` is shown in console.

After the second button press, `console.log` is shown with each consecutive button press.

How do I make `console.log` to show on the very first button press?

Also, I noticed, if I `alert` `user_id` (commented out in my code), the `console.log` is shown on the first button press, right after I close the alert window.

Comment: you should use FB.getLoginStatus on page load, on in the callback function of FB.login.

Comment: example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: either way, the main issue is that you want to access something that is only available in asynchronous callback functions